# Does scala support one default clause for many pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Consider a code below:

```
val first = ...
val second = ...
val third = ...
val fours = ...

first match {
  case "someString" => second match {
    case s:String => third match {
      case MyEnum.A => //some logic
      case MyEnum.B => fours match {
        case Some(old:String) => //some other logic
        case default=> defaulLogic
      }
      case default=> defaulLogic
    }
    case default=> defaulLogic
  }
  case default=> defaulLogic
}

private def defaulLogic()= {
    //log error here
}
```

Is there a way to put `case default` logic into one place instead of duplicating it in every pattern matching?

**Note**

There are only a top of `match-case` statments, actually there are more cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would rewrite the code to make it easier to read:

```
(first, second, third, fours) match {
  case ("something", s: String, MyEnum.A, _) => //some logic
  case ("something", s: String, MyEnum.B, Some(old)) => //some other logic
  case _ => defaulLogic
}
```

If you write it this way, the default case will be written in a more natural way.

Answer (score -1):

Not the most elegant idea, but...

```
try {
  first match {
    case "someString" => second match {
      case s:String => third match {
        case MyEnum.A => //some logic
        case MyEnum.B => fours match {
          case Some(old:String) => //some other logic
        }
      }
    }
  }
} catch {
  case me : MatchError => defaultLogic
}
```

Comment: Will try catch cut performace?

Comment: Only when no cases match and the MatchError is thrown. If the fall-through is rare, it'll be fast. If the fall through is a common case, then the overhead of construction the MatchError, capturing the stack trace, and the catching might matter.

Comment: This is dangerous. The exception might have been thrown inside of the `some logic` block and then it should not be handled by the `defaultLogic`.

Comment: Only as dangerous as pretty much any Exception handling. With try/catch, you have to be cognizant of the possibility that an Exception will be thrown from nested logic, and know what assumptions you can make about what you have caught. If the nested logic can throw MatchErrors, then sure, you've got to consider that. But if the nested logic includes only exhaustive pattern matches (or no pattern matches at all), or if the default is appropriate to MatchErrors that might be thrown from nested matches, then it's fine.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit more elegant :)

```
Try{
  first match {
    case "someString" => second match {
    case s:String => third match {
      case MyEnum.A => //some logic
      case MyEnum.B => fours match {
        case Some(old:String) => //some other logic
      }
    }
  }
}.getOrElse(defaultLogic)
```